# React and typescript ReactRouterProps issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I need to deconstruct my general props and match (to get an **"id"** from the URL).

> Component (using props):

```js
interface Props  extends RouteComponentProps<{id: string}>{
  initialProjectName: string;
  workspaceId: string;
}

const AddResources: React.FC<Props> = ({
  initialProjectName,
  workspaceId,
  match,
}) => {
  const projectId = match.params.id; // used here without any error
```

But the parent component is showing error when I pass props

> Parent

```js
<div>
      <h1>Start Project Page</h1>
      <AddResources
        initialProjectName={initialProjectName}
        workspaceId={workspaceId}   // error
      />
    </div>
```

#### Error Message

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By using `RouteComponentProps` you specify that your component requires the route props, but you will also need to make sure you pass these props. If the component is directly underneath a `Route` (i.e. as a child or by using `<Route component={..}/>`, the route props are passed automatically, if not, you can use `withRouter` ([docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter)) to obtain them:

```
const AddResourcesWithRouter = withRouter(AddResources);
```

and use `AddResourcesWithRouter` istead of `AddResources`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try useHistory, useRouteMatch, useLocation or wrap withRouter(AddResources)